# why do I set a variable for generator after setting a variable for a generator again ? (This case is different from ordinary generator examples)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, generator, data-visualization

After setting a variable for a generator like
let gene = generator();

Normally, What I need to do is 
gene.next() to iterating the generator made above.
However, in this example below, (For the full code, please refer to the link)

https://codepen.io/jotnajoa/pen/MWwzpJJ

another variable is set after set a variable for the generator again.
I don't know why this is happening. Also, I don't get the part of

```
let result = genratorAnimation.next();
//genratorAnimation.next();
let interval = setInterval(function(){
   if(!result.done) {
     genratorAnimation.next();
   }
   else {
    clearInterval(interval)
   }
}, 50);
```

At the end of this code.
Because, to my understanding, generator returns 'true' for 'done' when everything is yielded.

However, in this example, it is doing the opposite thing. which is "not result.done" which is false while running the generator.

Why is it?

As a summary,

1) why do I need to set another variable for interval.

I assumed, setInterval( ######## ) is enough, instead of let xxx = setInterval to run the loop.
because, if I set the variable for setInterval, 
nothing would happend till I type the variable 'xxx'. But in this code, it is running even if I do not call the variable.

2) Why    !result.done   makes the loop plays. 
because !result.done is false and if false is within if statement, things comes after if wouldn't run.

If statement runs only when the condition is true.
Isn't it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do I need to set another variable for interval.

[setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) is used to repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed time delay between each call. this means that the function provided to `setInterval()` function will be called and executed forever if its not stop by calling [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) function.

clearInterval() require a interval reference (variable), in this snippet we can have the code without clearing the interval but it will keep running and consume resources memory/CPU with no effect in the end so its better to remove it from the execution queue.

> Why !result.done makes the loop plays.

The generator function will keep returning `result.done` as `false` until its last result returned, it will return `true`: and [!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_!) (Logical NOT) used to negate a [Boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean) value so if `result.done` is false, `!result.done` will negate it and make it `true`. the way its written in your code snippet, is a matter of coding style it can be written as:

```
let result = genratorAnimation.next();
//genratorAnimation.next();
let interval = setInterval(function(){
   if(result.done) {
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
   else {
    genratorAnimation.next();
   }
}, 50);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Extremely clear!! I got the point that setInterval() is supposed to run infinitely. However, in the code snippet, for running setInterval, don't I have to type the variable at least once to initiate it? becuase just setting a variable doesn't mean that the variable is excuted. like let abc = function xxx{} itself doesn't excute xxx().

Comment: @Soonk, if you mean the `setinterval()` function its already executing and the variable will hold the value of `setInterval(function(){}, timeout);` which will be determined by the browser.

Comment: Let's say, 
you define a function and hold it as a variable like
var fun1 = function(){console.log('hi')};
it doesn't mean that the func1 is executed.

to excute it, I need to type
fun1() after it is defined.

However, here, 
let interval= setInterval(....) 
is excuted even if I didn't type
interval(); after the function is defined. Why?